# PHP pass value of checkbox to query

Tags: php, checkbox, pdo

Hello so I have this form with 3 checkbox:

```
<form action="send.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group" value="CID">CID
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group" value="OSDS">OSDS  
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group" value="SGO">SGO
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in my send.php I have this code:

```
$stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM tblcontactlist WHERE contactGroup=:cgroup");
$stmt->bindParam(':cgroup', $_POST['txt_group']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I think that if I check only 1 checkbox, this will work. But what if I select 2-3 checkbox? Will this query still work?

Comment: 1. You have to prepare your query 2. Are you sure you didn't wanted radio buttons ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant have same `name` for multiple `input`s if it is not an `array`, else they will be overwritten by the `last` one. Try with -

```
<form action="send.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="CID">CID
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="OSDS">OSDS  
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="SGO">SGO
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

With php an example query will be -

```
$values = implode("','", $_POST['txt_group']);
$values = $mysqli->real_escape_string($values);
"SELECT * FROM tblcontactlist WHERE contactGroup IN ('" . values . "')"
```

Comment: OP already uses PDO and now you make the code wide open for SQL-Injection.

Comment: And now you are writing code where you don't even know what it's doing

Comment: Sir you should use prepare not query

Comment: @b0s3 Now you removed the code, why? Because it's completely wrong and invalid ?!

Comment: @FewFlyBy You also don't have a prepared statement in your question, are you sure you know how to do it?

Comment: @Rizier123 I was not sure how to bind parameters with `IN` thats why.. Any problem with that?

Comment: @b0s3 ^ Yes, if you have problems with it, what's with OP? Will he have to live with this query, which is open to SQL-Injection ?

Comment: @FewFlyBy I'm out here, but just to let you know that 1. Your code as in your question is wrong and you don't prepare your statement nor 2. I'm not really sure if you know how to prepare your statement correctly so that leads to 3. Which makes it sad if you use PDO, but you make the code wide open to SQL-Injection

Comment: @b0s3 And you just make it worse and worse, 1. OP uses PDO 2. `mysqli_*` doesn't have `bindParam`, there it is: `bind_param`.

Comment: @Rizier123 I think there is no `bind_param` in the answer and the answer contains an example not exact solution

Comment: @Rizier123 Can you make your own answer then?

Answer (score 2):

change the input name to array

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="CID">CID
```

then `$_POST['txt_group']` get an array list of you checked

Answer (score 1):

On your code you are given same name for all checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group" value="CID">CID
```

Try to change name as array like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="CID">CID
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="OSDS">OSDS  
<input type="checkbox" name="txt_group[]" value="SGO">SGO
```

and print it on server side using

```
print_r($_POST['txt_group']);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, a square bracket for the variable name is necessary if you are to post values as an array.. this name="text_group[]" is correct ..